# How can be this xml parsed in efficient way?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am beginner in C#.

Simple Example of bigger case:

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <products>
  <product>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>John</name>
  </product>
  <product>
   <id>2</id>
   <name>Tom</name>
  </product>
  <product>
   <id>3</id>
   <name>Sam</name>
  </product>
 </products>
</xml>
```

**Output(for id=1):**

```
<id>2</id>
<name>Tom</name>
```

**My part code try psedocode:**

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Parse(".............");

 var els= doc.Descendants("product");
 foreach(e in els){
     node=e.Element("id");
     if(2==node.Value){
     return e;
   }
 }
```

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently your xml file is not well-formatted - remove closing `</xml>` tag from your file to make it valid. And here is the query:

```
int id = 1;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var product = xdoc.Descendants("product")
                  .Where(p => (int)p.Element("id") == id)
                  .SingleOrDefault();
```

This query will return whole `<product>` element or `null` if match not found.

Also I believe product name will be enough for you to select (because you already have product id):

```
var name = xdoc.Descendants("product")
               .Where(p => (int)p.Element("id") == id)
               .Select(p => (string)p.Element("name"))
               .SingleOrDefault();
```

Returns `Tom` for `id = 2`

Comment: @Yosef just verified - no errors for me. Have you fixed your xml file? What kind of error do you receive?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for XPath:

```
root.XPathSelectElements(@"//products/product/id[text()='2']")
```

**Edit** To the comment: Directly getting the name: `//products/product/id[text()='2']/../name`

See full example

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(XML);
        foreach(var n in doc.Root.XPathSelectElements(
                 @"//products/product/id[text()='2']"))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Not that hard: '{0}'", n.Parent.Element("name").Value);
        }

        // Direct query for name:
        foreach(var n in doc.Root.XPathSelectElements(
                 @"//products/product/id[text()='2']/../name"))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Directly: '{0}'", n.Value);
        }
    }

    private const string XML = 
    @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <products>
            <product>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>John</name>
            </product>
            <product>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>Tom</name>
            </product>
            <product>
                <id>3</id>
                <name>Sam</name>
            </product>
        </products>";
}
```

Printing:

```
Not that hard: 'Tom'
Directly: 'Tom'
```

Comment: Thanks, I need also to print "name"

Comment: @Yosef why don't you? `Console.WriteLine("Not that hard: '{0}'", n.Parent.Element("name").Value)`. Prints _Not that hard: 'Tom'_

Comment: @Yosef I have adapted the sample to show an XPath that directly queries for the name instead

Answer (score 1):

This will return the `product` (as in your question) not the `id`

```
var product = doc.XPathSelectElement("//product[id and id[text() = '1']]");
```